# Center Nav items Bootstrap CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I cannot figure out how to center my Nav items with bootstrap. I've researched many posts here and I still can't figure it out. It's been a while since I've programmed in HTML and CSS (years) so I am VERY rusty. I'm hoping I will get the hang of it here pretty soon because petty things like this really bother me. I've tried many different things and attempted to follow many different simple tutorials, but I cannot figure out exactly what I need to do. Help!!!

CSS:

```
.nav {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav > li > a {
  display: block;
}

.nav > li > a:hover,
.nav > li > a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}

.nav > li > a > img {
  max-width: none;
}

.nav > .pull-right {
  float: right;
}

.nav-header {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 15px;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #999999;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav li + .nav-header {
  margin-top: 9px;
}

.nav-list {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.nav-list > li > a,
.nav-list .nav-header {
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.nav-list > li > a {
  padding: 3px 15px;
}

.nav-list > .active > a,
.nav-list > .active > a:hover,
.nav-list > .active > a:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background-color: #0088cc;
}

.nav-list [class^="icon-"],
.nav-list [class*=" icon-"] {
  margin-right: 2px;
}

.nav-list .divider {
  *width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  margin: 9px 1px;
  *margin: -5px 0 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
}

.nav-tabs,
.nav-pills {
  *zoom: 1;
}

.nav-tabs:before,
.nav-pills:before,
.nav-tabs:after,
.nav-pills:after {
  display: table;
  line-height: 0;
  content: "";
}

.nav-tabs:after,
.nav-pills:after {
  clear: both;
}

.nav-tabs > li,
.nav-pills > li {
  float: left;
}

.nav-tabs > li > a,
.nav-pills > li > a {
  padding-right: 12px;
  padding-left: 12px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  line-height: 14px;
}

.nav-tabs {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.nav-tabs > li {
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}

.nav-tabs > li > a {
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  line-height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
     -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
          border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}

.nav-tabs > li > a:hover,
.nav-tabs > li > a:focus {
  border-color: #eeeeee #eeeeee #dddddd;
}

.nav-tabs > .active > a,
.nav-tabs > .active > a:hover,
.nav-tabs > .active > a:focus {
  color: #555555;
  cursor: default;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
}

.nav-pills > li > a {
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
     -moz-border-radius: 5px;
          border-radius: 5px;
}

.nav-pills > .active > a,
.nav-pills > .active > a:hover,
.nav-pills > .active > a:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #0088cc;
}

.nav-stacked > li {
  float: none;
}

.nav-stacked > li > a {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.nav-tabs.nav-stacked {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.nav-tabs.nav-stacked > li > a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
     -moz-border-radius: 0;
          border-radius: 0;
}

.nav-tabs.nav-stacked > li:first-child > a {
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 4px;
          border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 4px;
          border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 4px;
}

.nav-tabs.nav-stacked > li:last-child > a {
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
          border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
          border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 4px;
}

.nav-tabs.nav-stacked > li > a:hover,
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked > li > a:focus {
  z-index: 2;
  border-color: #ddd;
}

.nav-pills.nav-stacked > li > a {
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.nav-pills.nav-stacked > li:last-child > a {
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}

.nav-tabs .dropdown-menu {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
     -moz-border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
          border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
}

.nav-pills .dropdown-menu {
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
     -moz-border-radius: 6px;
          border-radius: 6px;
}

.nav .dropdown-toggle .caret {
  margin-top: 6px;
  border-top-color: #0088cc;
  border-bottom-color: #0088cc;
}

.nav .dropdown-toggle:hover .caret,
.nav .dropdown-toggle:focus .caret {
  border-top-color: #005580;
  border-bottom-color: #005580;
}

/* move down carets for tabs */

.nav-tabs .dropdown-toggle .caret {
  margin-top: 8px;
}

.nav .active .dropdown-toggle .caret {
  border-top-color: #fff;
  border-bottom-color: #fff;
}

.nav-tabs .active .dropdown-toggle .caret {
  border-top-color: #555555;
  border-bottom-color: #555555;
}

.nav > .dropdown.active > a:hover,
.nav > .dropdown.active > a:focus {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-tabs .open .dropdown-toggle,
.nav-pills .open .dropdown-toggle,
.nav > li.dropdown.open.active > a:hover,
.nav > li.dropdown.open.active > a:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #999999;
  border-color: #999999;
}

.nav li.dropdown.open .caret,
.nav li.dropdown.open.active .caret,
.nav li.dropdown.open a:hover .caret,
.nav li.dropdown.open a:focus .caret {
  border-top-color: #ffffff;
  border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="navbar-wrapper">
      <!-- Wrap the .navbar in .container to center it within the absolutely positioned parent. -->
      <div class="container">

        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
          <div class="navbar-inner">
            <!-- Responsive Navbar Part 1: Button for triggering responsive navbar (not covered in tutorial). Include responsive CSS to utilize. -->
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <img class="brand" source="assets/images/logo.jpg"></img>
            <!-- Responsive Navbar Part 2: Place all navbar contents you want collapsed withing .navbar-collapse.collapse. -->
            <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
              <ul class="nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                <!-- Read about Bootstrap dropdowns at http://twbs.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#dropdowns -->
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Expos <b class="caret"></b></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li class="nav-header">Texas Expositions</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Longview</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Houston</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Austin</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Midland</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li class="nav-header">Other Expositions</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Louisiana</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Oklahoma</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
          </div><!-- /.navbar-inner -->
        </div><!-- /.navbar -->

      </div> <!-- /.container -->
    </div><!-- /.navbar-wrapper -->
```

EDIT: Found this CSS at the top of the index.html page and I believe this is where I would center the navbar items?

```
/* CUSTOMIZE THE NAVBAR
    -------------------------------------------------- */

    /* Special class on .container surrounding .navbar, used for positioning it into place. */
    .navbar-wrapper {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      z-index: 10;
      margin-top: 20px;
      margin-bottom: -90px; /* Negative margin to pull up carousel. 90px is roughly margins and height of navbar. */
    }
    .navbar-wrapper .navbar {

    }

    /* Remove border and change up box shadow for more contrast */
    .navbar .navbar-inner {
      border: 0;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
         -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
              box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    }

    /* Downsize the brand/project name a bit */
    .navbar .brand {
      padding: 14px 20px 16px; /* Increase vertical padding to match navbar links */
      font-size: 16px;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    }

    /* Navbar links: increase padding for taller navbar */
    .navbar .nav > li > a {
      padding: 15px 20px;
    }

    /* Offset the responsive button for proper vertical alignment */
    .navbar .btn-navbar {
      margin-top: 10px;
    }



    /* CUSTOMIZE THE CAROUSEL
    -------------------------------------------------- */

    /* Carousel base class */
    .carousel {
      margin-bottom: 60px;
    }

    .carousel .container {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 9;
    }

    .carousel-control {
      height: 80px;
      margin-top: 0;
      font-size: 120px;
      text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
      background-color: transparent;
      border: 0;
      z-index: 10;
    }

    .carousel .item {
      height: 500px;
    }
    .carousel img {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      min-width: 100%;
      height: 500px;
    }

    .carousel-caption {
      background-color: transparent;
      position: static;
      max-width: 550px;
      padding: 0 20px;
      margin-top: 200px;
    }
    .carousel-caption h1,
    .carousel-caption .lead {
      margin: 0;
      line-height: 1.25;
      color: #fff;
      text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    }
    .carousel-caption .btn {
      margin-top: 10px;
    }



    /* MARKETING CONTENT
    -------------------------------------------------- */

    /* Center align the text within the three columns below the carousel */
    .marketing .span4 {
      text-align: center;
    }
    .marketing h2 {
      font-weight: normal;
    }
    .marketing .span4 p {
      margin-left: 10px;
      margin-right: 10px;
    }


    /* Featurettes
    ------------------------- */

    .featurette-divider {
      margin: 80px 0; /* Space out the Bootstrap <hr> more */
    }
    .featurette {
      padding-top: 120px; /* Vertically center images part 1: add padding above and below text. */
      overflow: hidden; /* Vertically center images part 2: clear their floats. */
    }
    .featurette-image {
      margin-top: -120px; /* Vertically center images part 3: negative margin up the image the same amount of the padding to center it. */
    }

    /* Give some space on the sides of the floated elements so text doesn't run right into it. */
    .featurette-image.pull-left {
      margin-right: 40px;
    }
    .featurette-image.pull-right {
      margin-left: 40px;
    }

    /* Thin out the marketing headings */
    .featurette-heading {
      font-size: 50px;
      font-weight: 300;
      line-height: 1;
      letter-spacing: -1px;
    }



    /* RESPONSIVE CSS
    -------------------------------------------------- */

    @media (max-width: 979px) {

      .container.navbar-wrapper {
        margin-bottom: 0;
        width: auto;
      }
      .navbar-inner {
        border-radius: 0;
        margin: -20px 0;
      }

      .carousel .item {
        height: 500px;
      }
      .carousel img {
        width: auto;
        height: 500px;
      }

      .featurette {
        height: auto;
        padding: 0;
      }
      .featurette-image.pull-left,
      .featurette-image.pull-right {
        display: block;
        float: none;
        max-width: 40%;
        margin: 0 auto 20px;
      }
    }


    @media (max-width: 767px) {

      .navbar-inner {
        margin: -20px;
      }

      .carousel {
        margin-left: -20px;
        margin-right: -20px;
      }
      .carousel .container {

      }
      .carousel .item {
        height: 300px;
      }
      .carousel img {
        height: 300px;
      }
      .carousel-caption {
        width: 65%;
        padding: 0 70px;
        margin-top: 100px;
      }
      .carousel-caption h1 {
        font-size: 30px;
      }
      .carousel-caption .lead,
      .carousel-caption .btn {
        font-size: 18px;
      }

      .marketing .span4 + .span4 {
        margin-top: 40px;
      }

      .featurette-heading {
        font-size: 30px;
      }
      .featurette .lead {
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 1.5;
      }

    }
    </style>
```

Comment: do u mean this?? https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/7377/

Comment: No not that. I mean centered on the nav bar, instead of aligning to the left.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: I'm not fluent enough to create one.

Comment: can you point the exact element you want to center. is it "div.navbar-wrapper" or "div.container" or "div.navbar"

Comment: Try this: http://bootply.com/WTMCYovQMr

Comment: I want to center the items on the nav bar IE: Home, Contact, Purchase, etc.

Comment: @Skelly I don't need them spread out like that, but I want them centered. I cannot figure out which nav property I need to edit and what exactly I need to change.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of bootstrap and do something like this
https://jsfiddle.net/venudil/xLvr7L75/      `.`